# Passing selected item from ListView Android to another Activity throws a NullPointerException when loading the new activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am new to Android Development and I am trying to work on a mock app in order to learn better. In its current state it has a ListView that contains elements, however what I am trying to do is upon click of a ListView Item open a new activity and pass the text to a TextView widget in the new activity.

Here it is how I have been doing it so far.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView locName =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            String locValue = locName.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, locValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("location", locValue);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

And onCreate for my second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.payment_detail);
    TextView locTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationName);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("location");
    locTitle.setText(value);
    Toast.makeText(PaymentDetail.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


}
```

Both activities are defined in the Manifest, however I have no idea why this NPE shows up. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post the logcat for where, which line exactly the NPE shows up

Comment: Can you post your error log please.

Comment: and by the way, your toast is not going to show up, as you haven't called ".show();" at the end of Toast.makeText(ForBothActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Comment: Here it is guys. 04-04 16:24:41.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10136): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eazymocky/com.example.eazymocky.PaymentDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Rather than using                                                    TextView locName =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
String locValue = locName.getText().toString(); you can get by adapter values by position,                                   String locValue=YourAdapterClass)parent.getItem().getText().toString();

Comment: print the whole thing with a line above and below , you can find an "at" with ActivityName.java:31 where "31" is the line number

Comment: I have been looking at the issue over the weekend and apparently when I attempt to set text to the TextView in the second view the null pointer exception occurs. Otherwise, it does the switch correctly and the values are taken as they should when I tap the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

I did a sample app with an array of fruits

For MainActivity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String fruit = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fruit, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fruit", fruit);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

For SecondActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    TextView fruitName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fruit = intent.getStringExtra("fruit");
    fruitName.setText(fruit);
    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, fruit, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So instead of using getText() method, try to get the item at the position of your adapter and store that to a String.

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

check whether toast message is printing or not. Because you are clicking a list item. If you are using a custom row then it will be a layout. You have to traverse through the layout and pass the value. else if you are using a android list items then you have to get the string from the collection using the position value which you are clicking.